# Is it possible to invalidate azure cdn by delete-ting a file and re-uploading it?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, cdn, azure-cdn

I am having azure storage and using as it as cdn for my web application,now i want to invalidate my cdn content every time when i upload files to the storage account.

My question is that when i delete a file in azure storage container and upload it again with same name,Will it cause cdn to invalidate this file?(I am aware that appending file version to filename will cause cdn to invalidate that file,but in this case i need to monitor all old files and remove them which are not referenced now,which is my last resort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure does not yet support a purge, though it is rumored to be under development. Deleting an object from blob storage will not cause a purge because the object will still be subject to TTL. Only after the TTL has expired will the CDN check to see if the object is still valid, and [then remove it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680303.aspx).

Until Azure CDN implements a purge you either need to use versioning or [manage content expiration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680306.aspx).

Comment: just to comment on `versioning` part: Instead of generating CDN URL like this: `http://az1234.vo.msecnd.net/cdncontent/testblob.txt`, you append some query string: `http://az1234.vo.msecnd.net/cdncontent/testblob.txt?v=0.1`. When you deploy your new version, you update the query string to a new value, and thus your users will get the new content.

Comment: Main problem is,query string will force browser to fetch file from cdn again,but there is no guarantee that cdn is updated with modified file(as cdn periodically invalidates file and refreshes with storage account file)

Comment: We've had the same problem with Azure serving files after they had changed but before TTL expiry. We've switched to Amazon S3, it allows invalidations (note it costs money). Plus in our case it better serves asia, australia and south america.